# Dynamically generating a website for each user. Is using Gatsby to generate a good idea?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am creating a website where for every user there will be created a personal web site/book. There will be many reusable content and some will be based on user's input.

Right now I am figuring out that I will collate user inputs in a JSON and will use these to generate a site using Gatsby. However, generating static sites for each user doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Should I use Gatsby or should I use plain reactjs to display content?

Any thoughts would be welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is opinion based and depend heavily on your exact needs, so I'll try to stay general and give you ways to choose the best method by just listing the bad sides and some of the good sides.

Basically static websites are costly to generate when content change, but light to consult. So if changes are really limited in time (like, only when admin change some config), it may be a good idea to use gatsby.

Given the time gatsby takes to generate a website, do you want your users to wait that long before seeing their changes online? If no, then are you ready to launch a dev instance of gatsby everytime someone enter the admin area? Are you ready to make sure that you doesn't introduce security flaws of remote code execution by doing that?

Talking about security, gatsby generation isn't secure at all, because it just executes any code you feed at it. Are you ready to limit user inputs to avoid that? Are you ready to deploy the infrastructure needed to secure generation from each of your clients?

On the good side, once generated, you'll just host static websites, with all the benefits of really fast user experience, simple load balancing, and very simple infrastructure. It can be a key selling point for your service.

Another good point is that you can totally separate the infrastructure for generating websites (a builder instance, and a admin instance) from serving them (one or more static instances). Security is easier as you can separate requirements between the three parts and just pass json/html files around.

Comment: Thanks. I learnt it the hard way by experimenting. I will now using plain react using the data sources to render sites dynamically. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: Btw you can still use gatsby for this: just load data from component did mount and use setState to rigger a rerender.